# How can a npapi plugin get the WM_ACTIVATE message from the browser?

Tags: windows, npapi, browser-plugin

on Windows Platform, When I switch to another window,the Browser Will receive a WM_ACTIVATE message.
   Is there anyway to pass the WM_ACTIVATE message to the plugins?
   I have tried the NPP_HandleEvent,but it seems not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows `NPP_HandleEvent()` is used for windowless plugins only and they are windowed by default. So, unless you explicitly opted in for windowless, that would be the reason `NPP_HandleEvent()` is not getting called.

For windowed plugins, you need to subclass the plugin window to receive window messages (see e.g. [`Subclass()`](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/dom/plugins/test/testplugin/nptest_windows.cpp#l685) in Mozillas test plugin sources).

For windowless plugins (which should be preferred), `WM_ACTIVATE` is [not delivered to the plugin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPEvent).
Do you actually need to handle `WM_ACTIVATE` or do you need to know when the plugin is visible/focused? That can be determined by checking for 0-sized clip rects for `NPP_SetWindow()` and the focus events.
If you really need to know about window activation (why?), the next best thing i can think of would be listening to the `focus` DOM event on the window.

Comment: If i switch to another tag，the plugin **clipRect** will be 0-sized for **NPP_SetWindow()**,but if I switch to another window,it's not 0-sized.My browser is safari in Mac OS X.

Comment: As i said, it signals *visibility*, not window focus. Usually knowing wether the plugin element is visible and focused should be enough.

Comment: (Also, it's possible that some browsers don't send all the visibility notifications they should).